# Issue with SQL joining

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

[image]

I have tried this so far:

```
SELECT T1.P_id as id, T2.D_id, COALESCE(T2.count , 0) AS count 
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT P_id FROM Comp_prod WHERE company_id = '15'
) AS T1 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT D_id, P_id, COUNT(P_id) AS count
    FROM userlogs 
    WHERE company_id = '15'
      AND date BETWEEN 'daterstart' AND 'dateend'
    GROUP BY D_id, P_id
) AS T2 ON T2.P_id = T1.P_id
```

this is not working because I need to connect to another table:

> departments

how can I have another sub queries?

any solution? it MySQL I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
select 
      sub.C_id,sub.D_id,sub.P_id,count(Userlogs.D_id) 
from 
      (select Comp_prod.C_id,D_id,P_id from Comp_prod join Departments on 
       Comp_prod.C_id = Departments.C_id ORDER by Comp_prod.C_id asc, 
       Departments.D_id ASC, Comp_prod.P_id ASC) as sub 
   left join Userlogs 
      on 
          sub.C_id = Userlogs.C_id and sub.D_id = Userlogs.D_id  
          and sub.P_id = Userlogs.P_id 
group by 
      sub.C_id,sub.D_id,sub.P_id
```

Comment: there is problem with this query, gives error. I cant seem to figure it out

Comment: it finally worked! with few condition but works good. thank you

Comment: :) glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all rows, using `cross join` and then bring in the existing results (if any) for aggregation:

```
select d.c_id, d.D_id, p.P_id, count(ul.c_id) as cnt
from comp_prod p cross join
     departments d left join
     user_logs ul
     on ul.c_id = d.c_id and ul.d_id = d.d_id and ul.p_id = p.p_id
group by d.c_id, d.D_id, p.P_id;
```

Comment: @user4499992 . . . Your comment is vague.  Your sample code has a `where` clause that is malformed.  You should put the working `where` clause into this query., in the `on` clause.

Comment: select d.company_id, d.id, p.product_id, count(ul.company_id) as cnt
from company_product p cross join
     departments d left join
     userlogs ul
     on ul.company_id = d.company_id 
 and ul.department_id = d.id 
 and ul.product_id = p.product_id
 and ul.company_id = '15'
 and ul.created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-29'
group by d.company_id, d.id, p.product_id

Answer (score 1):

A normal inner join between comp_prod and department on the C_id will give you every combination of those (you can slim it down to C_id of 15 in the WHERE clause), then LEFT OUTER JOIN user_logs to get the matching ones. Use COUNT(C_id) so you count the number of rows where a match is found (ie, C_id is not null)

```
SELECT Comp_prod.C_id,
        Departments.D_id,
        Comp_prod.P_id,
        COUNT(Userlogs.C_id)
FROM Comp_prod
INNER JOIN Departments
ON Comp_prod.C_id = Departments.C_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Userlogs
ON Comp_prod.C_id = Userlogs.C_id
AND Comp_prod.P_id = Userlogs.P_id
AND Departments.D_id = Userlogs.D_id
WHERE Comp_prod.C_id = 15
GROUP BY Comp_prod.C_id,
        Departments.D_id,
        Comp_prod.P_id
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried it but cant seem to get the wright result? it only shows P_id exist in Userlogs, need to show as '0' even if it doesn't exist

Comment: the query looks nice, maybe I am missing a condition? or GROUP BY?

Comment: Just need to catch the COUNT being NULL and if so put out 0. So use _COALESCE(COUNT(Userlogs.C_id), 0)_ .